# Access File using FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS with a limit on cache size

Tags: c++, windows

I want to access a file uisng using FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS. But when a large file is accessed via FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS, huge memory consumption could result in bad system performance. Is there a way to put a limit on cache size for a specific file handle?

Comment: Pretty sure Windows doesn't have a (documented) way to set a limit on the amount of cache space devoted to a particular file.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please point me to the documentation.

Comment: You can flush the file system cache for a specific file by openening it from time to time with the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING flag. See http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2014/12/14/160652.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Windows doesn't provide a way to set a maximum cache size, but this is relatively easy to implement on your own.  Open the file with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` and implement your own cache with an LRU list to determine when to evict blocks.  Note that starting with Windows Server 2016, `FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS` is less aggressive about retaining data in the cache, so this is less of a concern.  Microsoft still recommends avoiding this flag, however.

Further reading: [Troubleshoot Cache and Memory Manager Performance Issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/subsystem/cache-memory-management/troubleshoot)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to control file buffering in Windows but you will need to ditch the C++ standard library and use low-level OS file I/O APIs. If you are still interested, start reading here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365199(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't see a way to control the cache size for a specific file

Comment: @SravanGoud, I think you would need to write your own buffering / cache with the low level APIs.